# Ursprung und Bedeutung von „Auge, @<username>“ in Social-Media-Postings

Tags: meaning, etymology, phrase

In Social-Media-Postings findet man gelegentlich die Formulierung *Auge, @<username>*. Ich vermute, sie wird gebraucht, um jemand auf etwas hinzuweisen, im Sinne von:

- Das betrifft dich, @<username>.
- Das könnte dich interessieren, @<username>.

Ist das korrekt? Was ist die genaue Bedeutung und was ist der Ursprung dieser Formulierung?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about German language.

Comment: @Olafant: Inwiefern gehört denn eine informelle Redewendung bzw. Formulierung *nicht* zur deutschen Sprache?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Das ist doch offensichtlich Internetsprech und unabhängig von der Forensprache.

Comment: Ich habe die Formulierung bisher nur auf deutsch und noch in keiner anderen Sprache gesehen.

Comment: Danke für die Umformulierung der Frage, @björn-friedrich.

Comment: Ich finde, nach der Umformulierung ist die Frage klar. Ich sehe auch nicht, warum das nicht zur deutschen Sprache gehören sollte. Daher habe ich für die Wiederereröffnung der Frage votiert.

Comment: Ich habe das in meinen mittlerweile 30 Jahren Internet noch nie gesehen. Bitte bring einen Beleg!

Answer (score 3):

Meinst du das Unicode-Symbol  („Auge“), das Unicode-Emoji ️ („Auge“) oder auch das Unicode-Emoji  („Augen“) ?

Das steht in der Kombination mit einem Namen sicher für *sieh mal, schau mal*, oder auch für *Augen auf!*

Comment: Ich habe es bisher nur ausgeschrieben als “Auge” gesehen. Aber vielleicht ist das Emoji der Ursprung.

Comment: -1, denn deine "Antwort" ist eine Rückfrage zum Verständnis und keine Antwort, sie sollte ein Kommentar sein.